# Как сгруппировать объект по часам.

Tags: javascript

```
[{'time': "2016-01-01T12:10", 'value': 2000}, 
 {'time': "2016-01-01T12:30", 'value': 1200},
 {'time':"2016-02-02T14:00", 'value': 550}, 
 {'time':"2016-02-02T15:00", 'value': 1000}];
```

Добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста как лучше всего сгруппировать данный массив в массив объектов вида на JS

```
[
 {date: '2016-01-01', 
  hours: '12:00 PM', 
  valye: {'time': "2016-01-01T12:10", 
          'value': 2000},
         {'time': "2016-01-01T12:30", 
          'value': 2000}
  },
  ...
 ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотрите какое было придумано (TS):

```js
var dates = [{
    'time': "2016-01-01T12:10",
    'value': 2000
  },
  {
    'time': "2016-01-01T12:30",
    'value': 2000
  },
  {
    'time': "2016-01-01T13:10",
    'value': 2000
  },
  {
    'time': "2016-01-02T13:00",
    'value': 1200
  }, ,
  {
    'time': "2016-02-02T15:00",
    'value': 1000
  },
  {
    'time': "2016-02-12T14:00",
    'value': 550
  }
];

function calc(dates) {
  var responses = {};
  dates.forEach(function(d, i) {
    var date = new Date(d.time);
    var day = date.getDate();
    var hour = date.getHours();
    var key = `${date.getHours()}-${date.getDate()}`;
    var optionsHours: TimeOptions = {
      hour: 'numeric',
      minute: 'numeric'
    };
    var optionsDay: TimeOptions = {
      year: 'numeric',
      month: 'long',
      day: 'numeric'
    };
    var response = responses[key];
    if (!response) {
      response = responses[key] = [];
    }
    response.push({
      'day': date.toLocaleString("en-US", optionsDay),
      'hours': date.toLocaleString("en-US", optionsHours),
      'value': d
    });


  });
  console.log(responses);
  return responses;
}

calc(dates);
```

Надеюсь что это кому-то еще пригодиться (TS):

```js
const optionsHours: TimeOptions = {
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: 'numeric'
};
const optionsDay: TimeOptions = {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'long',
  day: 'numeric'
};

var dates = [{
    'time': "2016-01-01T12:10",
    'value': 2000
  },
  {
    'time': "2016-01-01T12:30",
    'value': 2000
  },
  {
    'time': "2016-01-01T13:10",
    'value': 2000
  },
  {
    'time': "2016-01-02T13:00",
    'value': 1200
  }, ,
  {
    'time': "2016-02-02T15:00",
    'value': 1000
  },
  {
    'time': "2016-02-12T14:00",
    'value': 550
  }
];


function calc(dates) {
  var responses = [];
  var response;
  var lastKey = '';
  dates.forEach(function(d, i) {
    var date = new Date(d.time);
    var day = date.getDate();
    var hour = date.getHours();
    var key = `${date.getHours()}-${date.getDate()}`;

    if (key != lastKey) {
      response = {
        'day': date.toLocaleString("en-US", optionsDay),
        'hours': date.toLocaleString("en-US", optionsHours),
        'value': []
      };
      responses.push(response);
      lastKey = key;
    }
    response.value.push(d);


  });
  console.log(responses);
  return responses;
}

calc(dates);
```

Comment: ключ у тебя совпадет если в массиве будут разные месяцы, например:  `{'time': "2016-01-01T12:30", 'value': 2000}` и `{'time': "2016-02-01T12:30", 'value': 2000},` попадут в одну группу

Comment: и добавь, что за язык ты использовал, потому что в яваскрипте такое объявление `var optionsDay: TimeOptions = {` является синтаксической ошибкой

Comment: Я писал для Tipe Script забыл убрать определение типов. 
А по поводу ключа ты бесспорно прав. у меня просто данные не будут приходить больше чем за месяц . Но думаю не составит проблемы исправить этот метод на месяц и год.

Answer (score 1):

Так сделать не получится. В свойство объекта value можно записать либо массив с объектами, либо каждому объекту задать определённое имя, например, вот так:

```
var date = '2016-01-01',
    hours = '12:00 PM',
    data = [
        {'time': "2016-01-01T12:10", 'value': 2000}, 
        {'time': "2016-01-01T12:30", 'value': 1200},
        {'time':"2016-02-02T14:00", 'value': 550}, 
        {'time':"2016-02-02T15:00", 'value': 1000}
    ];

var output = [],
    obj = {};

obj.data = date;
obj.hours = hours;
obj.value = {};

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    obj.value[i] = data[i];
}

output.push(obj);

console.log(output);
```

Демо (TS):

```js
var dates = [{
    'time': "2016-01-01T12:10",
    'value': 2000
  },
  {
    'time': "2016-01-01T12:30",
    'value': 2000
  },
  {
    'time': "2016-01-01T13:10",
    'value': 2000
  },
  {
    'time': "2016-01-02T13:00",
    'value': 1200
  }, ,
  {
    'time': "2016-02-02T15:00",
    'value': 1000
  },
  {
    'time': "2016-02-12T14:00",
    'value': 550
  }
];

function calc(dates) {
  var responses = {};
  dates.forEach(function(d, i) {
    var date = new Date(d.time);
    var day = date.getDate();
    var hour = date.getHours();
    var key = `${date.getHours()}-${date.getDate()}`;
    var optionsHours: TimeOptions = {
      hour: 'numeric',
      minute: 'numeric'
    };
    var optionsDay: TimeOptions = {
      year: 'numeric',
      month: 'long',
      day: 'numeric'
    };
    var response = responses[key];
    if (!response) {
      response = responses[key] = [];
    }
    response.push({
      'day': date.toLocaleString("en-US", optionsDay),
      'hours': date.toLocaleString("en-US", optionsHours),
      'value': d
    });


  });
  console.log(responses);
  return responses;
}

calc(dates);
```

Answer (score 1):

За один приём не получится, лучше использовать промежуточный словарь с ключом в виде дата + часы без минут:

```js
var arr = [{
    'time': "2016-01-01T12:10",
    'value': 2000
  },
  {
    'time': "2016-01-01T12:30",
    'value': 1200
  },
  {
    'time': "2016-02-02T14:00",
    'value': 550
  },
  {
    'time': "2016-02-02T15:00",
    'value': 1000
  }
];

var grouped = {};

arr.forEach(function(obj) {
  var m = moment(obj.time);
  var key = m.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH");

  if (key in grouped)
    grouped[key].push(obj);
  else
    grouped[key] = [obj];
})

console.log(grouped);

var result = [];

for (key in grouped) {
  var obj = grouped[key];
  var m = moment(obj.time);
  var val = {
    date: m.format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
    time: m.format("hh:00A"),
    value: obj
  };

  result.push(val);
}

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.3/moment.min.js"></script>
```